# Is it possible in java to make generic with unstable number of classes?

Tags: java

If I have an interface like this:

```
interface MyGenericInterface <T extends ...> {
  doSomething(T t);
}
```

I want to have possibility to implement it as:

```
class MyClass implements MyGenericInterface <MyObject> {
  doSomething(T t);
}
```

and at the same time:

```
class MyClass implements MyGenericInterface <MyObject, MyObject2> {
  doSomething(MyObject t, MyObject2 t2);
}
```

is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: No, not possible. You'd have to define two separate interfaces. After all, the methods have different signatures, so you wouldn't be able to invoke the method generically.

Comment: When MyObject and MyObject2 have a common parent class (except `Object`), then you can use `T extends ThatParentClass` and `doSomething(T... t)`. But a generic varargs in `T extends ...` is not possible.

Comment: No, that's not possible. What you want to do like this? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I just dont want to have 1 interface instead of 2 interfaces with method `doSomething(T1 t1, T2 t2)` and `doSomething(T t)`